# I want to make a simple chat program with twisted in python

Tags: python

I installed twisted with "pip install Twisted==21.2.0rc1"

and then When I run this code, I get error like this.

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor


class Chat(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print("connected")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print(data)


class ChatFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Chat()


print("Server started!")
reactor.listenTCP(8000, ChatFactory())
reactor.run()
```

error :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twisted'

But when I check my modules with "pip freeze" I get this :

Twisted==21.2.0rc1
twisted-iocpsupport==1.0.0

what should I do...?

I'm using python 3.9.0 64-bit & windows

Comment: Most certainly you've installed twisted on different python version.

Comment: Could you have more than one version of Python installed?

Comment: try `pip3 install Twisted`

Comment: @Ajay same result..